# destination path in python program

Tags: python

So i'm writing a program for my programming lessons.
This is a small part of it:

```
    os.system('python "C:/Users/wikto/desktop/frelich_wiktor_program_zaliczeniowy/imieninywybor.py"')
```

And there's a one problem. When im going to send this to my teacher he wouldn't be able to reach the correct file, because the destination path is attached to my device (frelich_wiktor_programam_zaliczeniowy is the name of the file). So, how can i change destination path that we both can open the file correct?

Comment: Try using relative paths? Also calling a python script with `os.system` is a bit messy. Consider importing it instead?

Comment: I'm going to use relative path, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has actually a quite easy fix: you should be able to 1. Put the second Python program in the same file as the one that has the line of os.system('python "C:/Users/wikto/desktop/frelich_wiktor_program_zaliczeniowy/imieninywybor.py"'). Then you would not have to put the path in the os command, but you would just have to put the name of the program in, and 2. By simply knowing that the program has a direct link to the folder where the first program (the one that contains said line) is, you can just cd inside the folder. This would look something like this:
os.system("cd freilich_wiktor_program_zaliczeniowy")
os.system("python imieninnywybor.py)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the other file in the same directory as the main one, and send him both files together. Just ask him to place the other file in the same directory as the main file. To do so you need to replace your command line with :
`ˋ`os.system(python imieninywybor.py )ˋ`ˋ
I hope this will be helpful to you...

Answer (score 0):

Using relative paths:

```
import os

# get the working directory
base_path = os.getcwd()

# this is the name of your file (with the 'py' extension)
your_file_name = "imieninywybor.py"

# Concatenate the file to your path
full_path = os.path.join(base_path, your_file_name)
```

Hope this helps :)